# I want to align my heading according to my paragraph. Is it possible?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a problem with my CSS. The content after the top nav is not aligned correctly. I used `float: left` and `right` in my code and then applied a clearfix to align the next header, but it is not working for me. I want the heading to align to the paragraph.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

#top-bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 51px;
  background: #ba2e1f;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#top-bar ul li {
  display: inline;
  line-height: 51px;
  padding: 0 7px 0 0;
  float: left;
}

#top-bar ul li a {
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  padding: 0 6px 0 0px;
  color: white;
  display: inline;
}

#top-bar input {
  float: right;
  height: 25px;
  width: 210px;
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}

#container {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div id="top-bar">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Sign Up</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Login</a></li>
      <li><a href="">RSS Feeds</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Archived News</a></li>
    </ul>
    <input type="search" placeholder="Search..">
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="container">
  <header>
    <h1>My new Project</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate, minus.</p>
  </header>

  <nav></nav>
  <section id="intro"></section>
  <section id="content"></section>
  <footer></footer>
  <div id="foot"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I understood this right and you want the heading to align left, I posted my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of time for the alignment you have to target the parent div. So if you want your heading to be aligned to left, You must target the parent element in this case the header.Replace your html header element with this and
Add this to your CSS and you should be good.You can rename the class if you want.
HTML:

```
  <header class="test">
    <h1>My new Project</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate, minus.</p>
  </header>
```

CSS:

```
.test {
  float:left;
}
```

And if you want both of them to be centered you can use,

```
.test {
  float:center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Hope this helps, let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: Thanks yash. It helps a lot.

Comment: you are welcome, please mark it right if the solution worked for you

Answer (score 0):

will you try this code ?

```css
header {display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; width: 100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure about your problem. When I look at what you did, I see the Header and the text on the same left alignment...

However, I suggest to use Flex-box instead of floats. Floats get messy and should only be used for in-paragraph stuff (such as news articles).

```css
 * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

#top-bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 51px;
  background: #ba2e1f;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#top-bar ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 51px;
  padding: 0 7px 0 0;
}

#top-bar ul li a {
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  padding: 0 6px 0 0px;
  color: white;
}

#top-bar input {
  height: 25px;
  width: 210px;
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}

#container {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div id="top-bar">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Sign Up</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Login</a></li>
      <li><a href="">RSS Feeds</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Archived News</a></li>
    </ul>
    <input type="search" placeholder="Search..">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="container">
  <header>
    <h1>My new Project</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate, minus.</p>
  </header>

  <nav></nav>
  <section id="intro"></section>
  <section id="content"></section>
  <footer></footer>
  <div id="foot"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Jakobsen. It helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Just encapsulate your text and title in a div, then with your class, add a text-align-center,
important: be careful not to put properties directly on your tag. rather prefer classes to modify multiple elements or id for single elements

```css
.block{
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<header>
      <div class="block">
         <h1>My new Project</h1>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate, minus.</p>
      </div>
  </header>
```

Comment: Thanks vincent. It helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
  #container {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  }
  #container header h1{
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  }
  #container header p{
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  }
```

You have to make div an inline-block element. To make changes to h1 as h1 is block level element.

[h1 is block level element.](https://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html_blocks.asp)

Comment: Thanks Deepak. It helps a lot.